# Can't get EF one-to-many relationships to work in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have these two models:

`TicketsUser` is a custom model inheriting from `IdentityUser`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Tickets.Models;

namespace Tickets.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the TicketsUser class
    public class TicketsUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the `Department` model is this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Tickets.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace Tickets.Models
{
    public class Department
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TicketsUser> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in `ApplicationDbContext` I have this code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Tickets.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Tickets.Models;

namespace Tickets.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
                .HasMany(d => d.Users)
                .WithOne(u => u.Department)
                .HasForeignKey("DepartmentID");
        }

        public DbSet<Department> Department { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TicketsUser> TicketsUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the database those two tables look fine:

[database capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A79On.png)

In a razor view the back code is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Tickets.Data;
using Tickets.Models;

namespace Tickets.Pages.Departments
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Tickets.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(Tickets.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<Department>  Departments { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
           Departments = await _context.Department.Include(d => d.Users).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

There are no errors, but the `Departments` property never loads the users, they are always returned as null.

I've been reading posts and documentations but didn't find the answer.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

I want to get the Users that belongs to a department using eager load, remember that my user model is an extension of `IdentityUser` class.

In the database there are a Department Administrators with the only user SuperAdmin, those records are generated by a seeder in which I create the Department, then create the user and assign the Department model to the department property of the user, and after saving changes the user record reflects the DepartmentID fine, so I thought that the relations where well configured.

I put the manual binding in OnModelCreating() after searching for solutions, also the Attribute ForeignKey was added then.

I also drop the database and recreated after every try, the database structure remains fine always.

Here a partial capture of the database diagram
[database capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUfc8.png)

and here the user record created by the seeder and the relation with the department table.
[record in table aspnetusers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnAzu.png)

and a sql query for department where id = 1 join with users[query in sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TtuO.png)

here a capture of the classDiagram in VisualStudio
[diagram section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc9yW.png)

sql query generated by EF:

```
SELECT [d].[ID], [d].[Name], [t].[Id], [t].[AccessFailedCount], [t].[ConcurrencyStamp], [t].[Discriminator], [t].[Email], [t].[EmailConfirmed], [t].[LockoutEnabled], [t].[LockoutEnd], [t].[NormalizedEmail], [t].[NormalizedUserName], [t].[PasswordHash], [t].[PhoneNumber], [t].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [t].[SecurityStamp], [t].[TwoFactorEnabled], [t].[UserName], [t].[DepartmentID]
FROM [Department] AS [d]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Discriminator], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName], [a].[DepartmentID]
    FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
    WHERE [a].[Discriminator] = N'TicketsUser'
) AS [t] ON [d].[ID] = [t].[DepartmentID]
ORDER BY [d].[ID], [t].[Id]
```

the line in this query,  WHERE [a].[Discriminator] = N'TicketsUser', is the problem here, I'll put the code to seed the database with user SuperAdmin below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Tickets.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Tickets.Data;

namespace Tickets.Models.Seeders
{
    public class AdminUserSeeder
    {
        public static async Task InitializeAsync(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            using var context = new ApplicationDbContext(
                serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<
                    DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>());

            var userManager = serviceProvider.GetService<UserManager<TicketsUser>>();
            var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

            // Set roles
            foreach (ValueEnums.EnumNames.Roles role in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ValueEnums.EnumNames.Roles)))
            {
                string rol = role.ToString();
                if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(rol))
                {
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(rol));
                }
            }

            // Look for SuperAdmin Operator.
            if (context.TicketsUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == "SuperAdmin") != null)
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }
            else
            {
                var user = new TicketsUser
                {
                    Email = "sadmin@ticketsys.com",
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    UserName = "SuperAdmin",
                };
                // set password
                var password = new PasswordHasher<TicketsUser>();
                var hashed = password.HashPassword(user, "Password*23");
                user.PasswordHash = hashed;

                if (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName) == null)
                {
                    var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "SuperAdmin");
                    }
                }

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                // add department
                var userDepartment = context.Department.FirstOrDefault(dept => dept.Name == "Administradores");
                if (userDepartment != null)
                {
                    user.Department = userDepartment;
                }

                context.TicketsUsers.Update(user);
                context.SaveChanges();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

the thig is that the generated record do not fill the Discriminator field so the include query fails to find a result. But this Discriminator field it's hidden for developers, then, how do I update it?

Comment: Are you sure you have related data for each department with corresponding Id & users?

Comment: Remove the manual binding in _OnModelCreating()_, remove the _ForeignKey_ attribute on _TicketsUser.Department_ property and add the property _int DepartmentID_ to _TicketsUser_. If the users stay empty, check if database really contains users for this department. To ensure DB is setup correctly create a new database context in DB first approach and compare the generated files with your current setup for differences.

Comment: I edited the question, about your comments. Do I need to give more detail maybe? If so, tell me what it's needed.

Comment: @Oliver, I scaffold the user table when I add the Identity for local account management, then create the TicketUser class to extend it and add the departments relationship

Comment: Maybe you can try to log the generated sql query.

Comment: I add the sql query to the question, @vernou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer.

The problem was that at scaffolding time when I add the Identity through Visual Studio, in order to use a custom user model, the scaffold wizard tells to make a new `dbContext` and then it lets you select the custom model, so I ended up with two DbContexts:
`ApplicationDbContext.cs` and `TicketsContext.cs`.

Then I struggled with them in the `Startup.cs` file, and the generated `IdentityHostingStartup.cs` file.

Here is the content of `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

As we can see, I use the `ApplicationDbContext` here and in the `IdentityHostingStartup` where the `TicketsContext` class used so I change to `ApplicationDbContext`.

This is `IdentityHostingStartup.cs`:

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            //services.AddDbContext<TicketsContext>(options =>
            //    options.UseSqlServer(
            //       context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<TicketsUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        });
```

also commenting the services.addDbContext lines was the solution, now when the SuperAdmin user gets created, the Discriminator field it's well populated with the class name TicketsUser and the relations works fine.

Thanks to all for guide me through this issue.

I think that the scaffold of Identity should let you select a custom class for user identity without having to generate other dbContext class.